# How to view detailed activities of a repo on GitHub?

Tags: github

I was able to see all details of activities on GitHub, such as who made a pull request, who put a comment on the pull request, etc.  But for some reason, once I navigated out of that page a few days ago, I was never able to get back to such a page and find it again on GitHub.

(The "pulse" doesn't have such info as it is a higher level summary.)

How can the detailed activities page be shown on GitHub?

P.S. with the greatest effort to find it, it turns out the page might simply be https://github.com  but it lists all repos that I was involved in previously, instead of just the repo I want to look at.  So I wonder if there is a way to see what https://github.com is listing except it is for a particular repo only.

Answer (score 0):

That pretty much sounds like the "Notifications" page. When logged in, click on the "Bell" symbol top right; you'll be taken to

https://github.com/notifications

Comment: hm... I still don't see the pull requests and the comments added activities... only see commits, i think

Comment: Well, then your account is broken. My notifications lists all the PRs I made, PRs to repos where I have merge authority, and so on

Comment: but last time I did see them... do you see "somebody made a comment..." for the pull request, etc?